# How to run a function when tableviewcell is selected (for example, update UIImageView when cell is pressed)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm making an app that has a collection table view that when a cell is selected it segues into another view controller with a tableview.

I want to use this tableview to update a UIImageView in my VC. So let say i press "Situps" on the TBC i want the imageview to update to an animation that shows situps. Hope someone can understand what im trying to do, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` is called when a cell is tapped on.
You can insert your logic to either segue to another `viewController` or update an `imageView` in the same `viewController` in this method.

for Swift 3.0:

```
override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  //your code...
}
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite simple.
use method.

```
                 tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)
```

then put your method here inside did select and you can navigate to viewcontroller you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    //so you can do whatever you want on your cell


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can trigger any action of a cell using the didSelect delegate method of Tableview but...

I think that what you are trying to do is to make an update in one VC from other? is that the case, what you need is to use delegation or NSNotificationCenter to send updates between classes.